# The Fanatic Badge

Tags: shabbat, calendar, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz, stackexchange

Here on Mi Yodeya, one can earn the "Fanatic" badge for visiting the site for 100 consecutive days.

Is it halachically possible to earn the fanatic badge in the Diaspora?

Comment: Move back to main. This is a question about Jewish life and learning (are there 100 UTC days in a row on which _m'lacha_ can be done), albeit worded in a meta way.

Comment: @msh210 Is this question relevant in any non-meta context?

Comment: @IsaacMoses: If it were worded "Physics.SE has [a 'Fanatic' badge](http://physics.stackexchange.com/badges/23/fanatic) for those who visit the site 100 UTC days in a row. Is there an halachic way to earn this badge in the Dispora?" you'd allow it on main, wouldn't you? I mean, that's certainly not meta (on Judaism.SE). I don't see why the present question is worse.

Comment: @msh210 Oh, alright. @Tzvi Sorry for apparently robbing your user account of its association with this question.

Comment: Now we're having a discussion _about_ what belongs in the meta-discussion. . .

Comment: @WAF http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-meta

Comment: We ought to ask the question on meta about whether we should change the terms of the badge.

Comment: While there are meta elements to this question, I put it in Main because the underlying question was whether there were 100 days without a two-day yom tov. In the event, I forgive you, Isaac (but now I can't accept jake's answer).

Comment: Is this a question about Judaism or about calendars and math?

Comment: @SethJ It is most definitely a question about Judaism! We ask questions here about running a computer script or batch job on Shabbos, or receiving faxes and similar. This is a charming question! I only wish I had thought to ask it myself.

Answer (score 22):

Yes.

The website uses UTC time. Since I live on the west coast in the US, each "website day" starts at 5 PM. Thus, I simply visit the site after 5 PM on Friday, which during the summer months is not yet Shabbos, and then visit again before 5 PM on Sunday. As far as the website is concerned, I just visited on two consecutive days.

The only remaining problem is to find an 100 day stretch without Yom Tov Sheni. For this, the stretch between Shavuos and Rosh Hashana works. Tamuz + Av + Elul = 88 days + remaining days of Sivan = 111 days.

Comment: To get the 111 day stretch between Shavuot and Rosh HaShanah, you'd have to do it in a year when Tisha b'Av didn't fall out on a Sunday.

Comment: @Chanoch: why? You can't learn Torah on Tish'a B'Av, granted, but there shouldn't be anything wrong with visiting the site and reading some question about things that it's permissible to learn.

Comment: @Alex, or pop into Meta. On the way, you're likely to go through the main site too...

Answer (score 11):

Now that we've moved the clocks, I realized that it's possible to do the inverse of @jake's answer from the eastern time zone: shabbat ended this week before 6PM, so if I'd thought of it I could have gotten credit for the day by visiting in that last hour (7PM EST = midnight UTC).  Shabbat won't end after 7PM again until March 10, and there are no chagim in that stretch.

Update: I did that.

Answer (score 7):

Well it's *technically* possible to write a script (and I'm sure there have been scripts written already), but an important thing to note is that the homepage doesn't count for a visit, as well as "similar pages" ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485)). [and there may even be more secret algorithms preventing something like that]

Of course, we would then have to analyze whether this would actually be permitted, and not some form of lying/stealing.

And, [Computer working on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/computer-working-on-shabbos) might apply here...

There's a nice looking calendar that you can access on your profile page (click on "x days" next to visited). Mine looks like:

[image: visit calendar]

No surprise there...

Comment: also, it might be maris ayin